# Смежный выбор в контекстном меню у фрагментов

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-context-menu

У меня есть фрагменты, а у них два метода для создания контекстного меню:

```
public class PagePhrases extends Fragment {
    private String TAG = "myApplication";
    private String MSG = "MSG: ";

    private View viewForOpenContextMenu = null;
    private int itemPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table, null);
        viewForOpenContextMenu = view.findViewById(R.id.viewForOpenContextMenu);

        ...
        ...
        ...

        return view;
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    public void onLongItemClick(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "PAGE PHRASES 1");
        itemPosition = position;

        registerForContextMenu(viewForOpenContextMenu);
        getActivity().openContextMenu(viewForOpenContextMenu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "PAGE PHRASES");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Удалить = " + itemPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Изменить = " + itemPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "PAGE PHRASES 2");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, R.string.context_menu_item_1);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, R.string.context_menu_item_2);
    }
}
```

и

```
public class PageWords extends Fragment {
    private String TAG = "myApplication";
    private String MSG = "MSG: ";

    private View viewForOpenContextMenu = null;
    private int itemPosition = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table, null);
        viewForOpenContextMenu = view.findViewById(R.id.viewForOpenContextMenu);

        ...
        ...
        ...

        return view;
    }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    public void onLongItemClick(int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "PAGE WORDS 1");
        itemPosition = position;

        registerForContextMenu(viewForOpenContextMenu);
        getActivity().openContextMenu(viewForOpenContextMenu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "PAGE WORDS");
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Удалить = " + itemPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Изменить = " + itemPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        Log.i(TAG, MSG + "PAGE WORDS 2");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, R.string.context_menu_item_1);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, R.string.context_menu_item_2);
    }
}
```

Вот разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/table_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewForOpenContextMenu"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Проблема в том, что `onLongItemClick` и `onCreateContextMenu` вызываются для одного фрагмента, а, при выборе пункта, `onContextItemSelected` вызывается сначала в одном, а потом в другом фрагменте! Но почему и как от этого избавится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего дело в одинаковых `ID` пунктов меню в разных фрагментах. Сделайте их разными (т.е. 1 и 2 в первом фрагменте и 3, 4 в втором) и должно нормально заработать.

Comment: Но почему метод `onContextItemSelected` вызывается в двух фрагментах?

Comment: @bukashka101, думаю, дело в том, что фрагменты в пейджере, оба уже добавлены в активити и, засим, все их элементы можно найти через активити. а при работе с контекстным меню андроид начинает искать в активити нужные ID и находит все, включая те, что во фрагментах.

Comment: Спасибо :), кстати, с праздником Вас!

Comment: @bukashka101, и вам спасибо) Но с каким?..

Comment: Ну, вроде как, день святого Николая. А! Забыл! У Вас же его не празднуют... :D

Comment: @bukashka101, ну, у меня вообще нет знакомых (кроме одного),  празднующих религиозные праздники) У нас тут типа светское государство, все дела)

Comment: Мы День победы празднуем, Новый год)

Comment: Я знаю :). Мы тоже все тоже празднуем. Я живу не так и далеко от Вас, в соседней стране. Разве что, из праздников, День Победы так испортили, хоть это и самый главный праздник... Но не будем о плохом.

Comment: @bukashka101, таки да) Так что с праздником вас и успехов на ниве кодописания)

Comment: Ахаха, спасибо :).